# Set JavaScript variable from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How I can set the JavaScript variable strUser from PHP?

I am using the following code:

```
<script>
function val()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ali");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

}
</script>
brand<select id="ali" onChange="val()">
<?php
   $brand=modsearchkhodroHelper::retrieve();
   foreach($brand as $item)
   {   
   ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $item['brand']?>" selected="<?php  $id=$item['brand']?>">
           <?php echo $item['brand']?>
       </option>
   <?php
   }
   echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: You can't. JavaScript communicates with PHP via AJAX.

Comment: Please, read more about HTTP and the way the web works. Javascript is executed by a web browser (client side), after the page have been generated by PHP on the server side. The two never "overlap": to the PHP side, Javascript is just a bunch of text to send to the client. To transmit information from the client to the server, you need a new HTTP request, triggered by a link, a form, an Ajax call...

Comment: You might need to explain your question better.

Comment: `selected="<?php  $id=$item['brand']?>"`... Shouldn't that be something along the lines of `<?php echo ($id==$item['brand'])?'selected="selected"':"" ?>` ? That would pre-select the item if it equals whatever is in variable $id..

Answer (score 19):

If you want to set the variable when the page loads, you could use something like this in the PHP code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var strUser = <?php echo json_encode($someVariable); ?>;</script>
```

Just make sure to remove the later variable declaration from the JavaScript.

If you want to set the variable after the page loads, you'll have to use an AJAX call to ge the value from the server.

Comment: This is the wrong way arround :) This is giving some php value to javascript not javascript to php (which is harder)

Comment: @Martijn From what I understood, the OP wanted to set a JavaScript variable from PHP. I think the title was wrong. I edited the question, but maybe I edited it wrong. It was fairly hard to understand.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD I json_encode the variable before passing it to JavaScript to make sure everything is escaped properly if it is a string. If it's an object, then json_encode will format it as a JavaScript compatible object that can be injected directly into the JavaScript code.

Comment: Hm, you might be right. Difficult question. Kinda odd, because placing phpinfo into a file with javascript is about the same as he is doing right now

Comment: @Martijn Either way he meant it, we've got an answer for each way. Hopefully the OP will be back soon to clarify what he meant. Until then, you can view the original version of the question by clicking the "Edited x minutes ago" link under the question.

Comment: @Martijn Easiest solution may actually be to flag the question as off-topic with this reason reason: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 5):

Use Cookie 
in your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
</script>
```

in your php

```
<?php 
   $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];

   echo $phpVar;
?>
```