# Convert laravel object to js array

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel. How to convert laravel object into js array. my coce is below..

```
$customer = new Customer();             
$result = $customer->where('client_state','like', '%'.$statename.'%')->get(array('client_state'));

echo $result;
```

result is...

```
[{"client_state":"Gujarat1"},{"client_state":"Gujarat"}]
```

but i need like this..

```
["Gujarat1","Gujarat"]
```

How it is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set JavaScript variable from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189198/set-javascript-variable-from-php)

Answer (score -1):

If you want your query to return an array of which values are set to values of your preferred column, then you would use a method `lists('your_column_here')` instead of `get()`

Try this:

```
$result = $customer->where('client_state','like', '%'.$statename.'%')->lists('your_column'));
```

Reference here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects