# How to incriment value is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would know how to increment a value inside a js.

I have this

My loop

```
<ul class="row list-unstyled" id="list">
  <?php
    $i = 0;

    while ($QoptionValue->fetch()) {
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Add a new card

```
<?php
  $card = '<li class="col-md-4" id="elementID' . $i . '">';
  $card .= '<div>';

  for ($l=0, $n=count($languages); $l<$n; $l++) {
    $card .= Language->getImage($languages[$l]['code']) . ' ' . HTML::inputField('option_value[' . $i . '][option_value_description][name][' . $l . ']', $options_name) . '<br />';
    $card .=  HTML::hiddenField('option_value[' . $i . '][option_value_description][language_id][' . $l . ']', $options_name);
}

 $card .= '</div>';
 $card .= '</li>';
?>
```

The js, I added a `var element` but it is not take in consideration

```
<script>
    var element = <?php echo $i; ?>

    $('#insert').click(function(){
       var str = <?php echo json_encode($card); ?>;
       // do the string replace
       var str = str.replace(/elementID/g, 'element'+element);
       $( "ul#list" ).append(str);
       // increment the element ID
       element++;
    });
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.close').click(function(){
      var $target = $(this).parents('li');
      $target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a str.replace in the javascript on the id before you append it to the list.

Set the element in the PHP to a string that can be replaced eg `elementID`

```
<?php
  $card = '<li class="col-md-4" id="elementID">';
  ....
  $card .= '</li>';
?>
```

In the javascript replace element ID with the incremented element ID

```
<script>
    var element = <?php echo $i; ?>

    $('#insert').click(function(){
       var str = <?php echo json_encode($card); ?>;
       // do the string replace
       var str = str.replace(/elementID/g, 'element'+element);
       $( "ul#list" ).append(str);
       // increment the element ID
       element++;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Tristant, With your approach $i take this : 00, 10, but I added some element and inside the loop the $i is always 0. Maybe I wrote something with little element. Sorry. Sso my second question what is $card because this element doesn"t have value in the code. See above . Tk.

Comment: The id in $card just needs to be a string that is replaced by str.replace in the javascript. You could use `$card = '<li class="col-md-4" id="zzzzz">';` as long as you use the same string in the js ie `var str = str.replace(/zzzzz/g, 'element'+element);`

Comment: ok tk I understand the approach. 
About the problem $i, a vaule is made id="elementID' . $i . ' but if I look the loop for $i it always at 0. 
It's important else it's impossible to save the data. 
Example of gernerated code : <input type="text" name="option_value[0][option_value_description][name][0]" class="form-control">

Comment: You'll need to use str.replace to replace any instances where $i needs to be replaced with the incremented id

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189336/10221765) - you need to JSON-encode the PHP variable first:

```
var element = <?php echo json_encode($i); ?>
```

Now your code should work.

Comment: I updated but the increment not work. No element inside the console. see above

Comment: No, you need to use the `json_encode($i)` bit to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how PHP works but `element++` should be inside the click callback.

```
$('#insert').click(function(){
  $( "ul#list" ).append(<?php echo json_encode($card); ?>);
    element++;
});
```