# Adding Aria label to append blog title to 'Read More' Button in JS file in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wai-aria

Currently I have a blog with standard 'Read More' buttons at the bottom of the homepage under each blog tile - for ADA compliance I need to append the blog title to the Aria label so the description instead for a screen reader will say "Read More On +'the blog title'".

I have tried the code below thinking I could just append the post title to the aria label but it doesnt seem to work.

```
jQuery(function($){
       $('.et_pb_button').attr({
      'aria-label': 'Read More On '.$post_title
    });
})
```

Comment: Is `$post_title` JavaScript variable?

Comment: At the time I was testing it I had seen it used in another Stack Overflow response but in playing around with it more I think it is just a PHP variable - but I was trying to work within a JS file where I have been making other ADA updates, I am just not very familiar with JS so struggling to find the right terms to append to the character string saying 'Read More '

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `post_title` is a JavaScript variable. For this you can do something like `var post_title='<?php echo $post_title; ?>';` Similarly, you can concat the string using `+` operator in JavaScript. So, your new JS will look as follows:

```
jQuery(function($){
       $('.et_pb_button').attr({
      'aria-label': 'Read More On ' + post_title
    });
})
```

Comment: Where would I put the var post_title='<?php echo $post_title; ?>';  - it cant run the php from within the js file can it?

Comment: https://dev.to/supunkavinda/how-to-create-javascript-variables-from-php-variables-11jn

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189198/set-javascript-variable-from-php

Comment: create JavaScript variable from PHP file. Not from js file

Comment: do something like `<script>
   var post_title='<?php echo $post_title; ?>';
</script>`

Comment: Because you cannot access `$post_title` php variable in js file. I hope you understand what I mean. :)

Comment: So can the var post_title be added as a script in functions.php to get this value and then the jQuery can use it?

Comment: @Axwell that's an interesting question, you can add it where your `jQuery(function($){
       $('.et_pb_button').attr({
      'aria-label': 'Read More On '.$post_title
    });
})` is called.